# Disribute PHP files after compiling from source

Tags: php, centos6, php-fpm, make, compilation

I have compiled and installed multiple version of PHP on my system. When I compile my PHP, there are a few files that are not copied to to their location. For example, when I compile my PHP v7.1(PHP-FPM), its service file (`./sapi/fpm/init.d.php-fpm`) is not copied to `/etc/init.d`. Is there any way to do this automatically? or it has to be done manually?

P.S: I use something like this to compile and install my PHP:

```
./configure --prefix=/php7 --with-config-file-path=/php7/php --with-config-file-scan-dir=/php7/php/php.d --enable-fpm ....
make
make install
```

Comment: What did you expect the flag `--prefix=/php7` would do? I imagine that prevents any file from getting copied outside of that directory ...

Comment: @HBruijn then what about `php.ini`? that file should've been copied because it's not outside of `/php7`.

Comment: Check what `make install` is supposed to do and then the logs to see why it fails *if* it's supposed to be copied to the `/etc/init.d` folder